# Flutter signin with email and password with validating the phone number with otp with firebase

Tags: flutter

**Need help**,
**i want to implement a signin function in my app using firebase, In this i can signin with email&password using firebaseauth package.But i want to implement another function to this
ie,
First the user will register by providing email ,password ,email ,phonenumber then after confirming i want to show another screen (otp screen) the user has to give the otp send to their given phone number and validate it then Registration will be completed and user can login with email and password**

**ie, user can only login if he is validate phone number with otp otherwise login will be failed**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: Email, password: 
   Password).then((result){
                        
  _auth.currentUser.linkWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).then((value) {}
}
```

and in phone verification method open the new screen on onCodeSent